# posting email address to Parse backend via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, parse-platform

I am having difficulty posting an email address via AJAX to a Parse backend. I have exhausted all encodeURIComponent and urlencode/urldecode options. This submits to Parse backend successfully as non-email text (ie. "test") whereas "test@test.com" returns a failure.

Chrome's Developer Tools shows the following:
Form Data: "email: test@test.com"
source: "email=test%40test.com"
url encoded: "email=test%40test.com".

Posting "test" returns a "200 OK", which is what Parse returns after a successful transaction, however, posting "test@test.com" returns status of "(canceled)."

Also, I can post manually via url "parse.php?email=test@test.com" and it will submit to Parse successfully.

Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

// AJAX SECTION

$('#subscribe').on('click', function()
{
    var email = $('#email').val();
    data = { email: email };

```
$.ajax({
    url: "parse.php",
    type: "post",
    data: data,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        $("#result").html('Submitted successfully');
    },
    error:function(data){
        alert(data.responseText);
        $("#result").html('There was an error while submitting the email');
    }
});
```

});

//// PHP SECTION

if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
{
    addEmail($_REQUEST['email']);
}

function addEmail($email)
{
    $appid = "HIDDEN";
    $restkey = "NOTFORYOU";

```
 $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Emails';  
 $headers = array(
   "Content-Type: application/json",  
   "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appid,  
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restkey
 );
 $objectData = '{"email":"' . $email . '"}';  
 $rest = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$objectData);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
 $response = curl_exec($rest);  
 echo $response;
 curl_close($rest);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It turns the form post was taking over the request, essentially canceling the AJAX request before it could even post to the server. I updated my form tag to read as follows: `<form method="post" onsubmit="return false;">` and that did the trick.